# Returning value from called function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I must write a code in C, that have an extra function with pointers as function arguments. This function have to perform a basic math calculation (such as +-*/) with those pointers, then send result back to the calling function main().

But I have no idea, how the called function can signalize that dividing by zero is undefined and send it back to the main()?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

char count(float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *); 
//prototype the function 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

float a, b, sum, diff, prod, div;

printf("\n a und b eingeben: ");

scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);

printf("\n a und b lauten: %f %f\n", a, b);

count(&a, &b, &sum, &diff, &prod, &div); //send addresses to function

printf("\n a+b = %f \n", sum);
printf("\n a-b = %f \n", diff);
printf("\n a*b = %f \n", prod);

if (b == 0) 
    printf("\n a/b ist nicht definiert\n\n");    //I wrote this just in 
                                                 //the main (), but it's 
                                                 //not the same exercise :))
else
    printf("\n a/b = %f \n", div);

return 0;
}

char count(float *a, float *b, float *sum, float *diff, float *prod, float 
*div) //define the function

{
*sum = *a + *b;

*diff = *a - *b;

*prod = *a * *b;

*div = *a / *b;

if (*div == 0)            //?????????????
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you're using `float`, how about assigning `NaN` if `b == 0`?

Comment: Well, you could, well, return something meaningful instead of void?  An enum, maybe, or an int.  Perhaps 0=success, 1=Div0, etc.   The number/enum could index an array of error messages.

Comment: `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`You lose 99% of the competent programmers by using these.

Comment: @wildplasser: Unlikely. Most competent programmers know what it is already.

Comment: @AnT: many  competent programmers code C programs for POSIX systems. They don't care about `_tmain`. For example, most VPS or cloud instances or HPC supercomputers (or tablets) run some POSIX system like Linux. BTW, I'm coding in C (sometimes coding generators of C code) since 1987 (using SunOS then Linux) and *never* used `_tmain` or Windows.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` is not in standard C11 or C99. Please **edit your question** to tell more about your system.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that you will get people to up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Answer (score 1):

if you include math.h and use std=c99, you can use

```
isinf(div)
```

to check if you divided by 0.

i.e.

```
if(isinf(div)) {
    printf("\n a/b is undefined\n\n");
}
```

Comment: division by zero is not infinity, it is undefined. Code should handle this *before* an attempted division by zero

Comment: Sure, mathematically, but it's how C handles it. 2.0/0.0 = INF, 0.0/0.0 = NaN, -2.0/0.0 = -INF. See [IEEE754 specs](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF)

Comment: @陳勝漢: C specification is not required to obey IEEE 754. And again, C standard says that division by zero is undefined behavior in C. That `NaN` that you observe in your case is nothing more that a specific property of your compiler, just one possible manifestation of that UB. It has nothing to do with C itself.